# iPhone: Issue disabling Auto-Cap/autocorrect on a UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

For some reason, even though I disable the auto-cap and auto-correct of my UITextField, it's still capitalizing the first letter of my input.

Here is the code:

```
UITextField* textField = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90.0, 10.0, 213.0, 25.0)] autorelease];
[textField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
textField.autocorrectionType = FALSE;
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
textField.delegate = self;
if (inputFieldType == Email) {
    label.text = @"Email:";
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
    emailTextField  = textField;
    textField.placeholder = @"Email Address";
} else { // password
    textField.secureTextEntry = TRUE;
    label.text = @"Password:";
    if (inputFieldType == Password){
        textField.placeholder = @"Password";
        passwordTextField  = textField;
    }
    if (inputFieldType == ConfirmPassword){
        textField.placeholder = @"Confirm Password";
        confirmPasswordTextField  = textField;
    }

}
```

See screenshot:
[alt text http://grab.by/39WE](http://grab.by/39WE)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You're setting `autocorrectionType` to `FALSE` as if it were a `BOOL`, but it actually has type `UITextAutocorrectionType`.  So `FALSE` is being interpreted as `UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault`, which means that autocorrection is probably enabled.

I bet it found the name "Phil" in your address book and is autocorrecting the capitalization to match.

Comment: Ha! I had the opposite problem. I had auto correction disabled correctly - but was setting auto capitalization to FALSE - d'oh!

Answer (score 40):

**Objective - C**

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.autocorrectionType = FALSE; // or use  UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo
    textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;

}
```

**Swift**

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textfield : UITextField)
{
    textField.autocorrectionType = .No
    textField.autocapitalizationType = .None
    textField.spellCheckingType = .No
}
```

**Swift3**

```
  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField : UITextField)
{
    textField.autocorrectionType = .no
    textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
    textField.spellCheckingType = .no
}
```

Comment: Hello Anbu, How we can enable the same option (    textField.autocorrectionType = FALSE; // or use UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo) for NSTextfield (Mac app). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

```
yourTextFieldName.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
yourTextFieldName.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

Answer (score 6):

Updated the correct answer for Swift 5

```
    textField.autocorrectionType = .no
    textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
    textField.spellCheckingType = .no
```

Comment: As per this answer, to fully disable some automatic word substitutions on the iPad, I had to add the `textField.spellCheckingType = .no` in addition to the `textField.autocorrectionType = .no` which I already had and assumed would turn off all kinds of automatic corrections

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2:

```
textField.autocorrectionType = .No
textField.autocapitalizationType = .None
```

Comment: Please, add a description of the solution youare proposing.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to disable Auto-Cap/autocorrect on a UITextField for whole project,

then make a class which will inherit the UITextField class and init method set the autoCorrectionType to "no".

```
Class AppTextField: UITextField {

     override init(frame: CGRect) {
         super.init(frame: frame)

         //setting the autocorrection to no
          self.autocorrectionType = .no
      }
}
```

Then in storyboard set the cusotom class for textfield to AppTextField.

[image]