# First letter in UiTextField lowercase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

How do you make it so that when you start typing on the keyboard after youve clicked on a UITextfield the first letter isn't a capital automatically?

Comment: The first two answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474824/iphone-issue-disabling-auto-cap-autocorrect-on-a-uitextfield) seem to answer this: it's not just an auto-capitalization, but also an auto-correction issue. Turn off auto-correct & that first letter of the text field won't be auto-capped for you.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

In Objective-C:

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

In Swift:

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
```

Comment: That doesn’t seem to do it for the very first letter; it’s as if it is starting a sentence.

Comment: @DavidDunham It's auto-correct that's doing that to you. Turn THAT off, and your first letter in the text field will remain lowercase.  The first two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474824/iphone-issue-disabling-auto-cap-autocorrect-on-a-uitextfield) show what you need.

Answer (score 17):

For SwiftUI,

```
TextField("I want entered text to be all lowercase", text:$myText)
     .autocapitalization(.none)
```

Answer (score 14):

You can turn off auto-capitalization with the [`.autocapitalizationType` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextInputTraits/autocapitalizationType) in the UITextInputTraits protocol.

```
textfield.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set capitalization for TextField in the Text Input Traits of Text Field Attributes in XIB(interface Builder).

Answer (score 5):

set setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone for UITextField.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift:

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.None
```

Comment: better yet, `textField.autocapitalizationType = .None`

Answer (score 4):

In Swift you can use the `autocapitalizationType` property:

```
yourTextField.autocapitalizationType = .none
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid completely there are three properties that we can set

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = .none;
```

and

```
textfield.autocorrectionType = .no;
```

and

```
textField.spellCheckingType = .no
```

**Only setting .autocapitalizationType = .none; works** but better we set other both the properties to avoid capitalising from autocorrection and spell checking.

Comment: How can I disable all capitals so the user cannot type it at all?

Comment: Hi @Outsider, implement shouldChangeCharactersIn delegate method for UITextField and then replace a range of string with string.lowercase() in that method and set yourTextField.autocapitalizationType = .none

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
textfieldname.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

Answer (score 1):

this code will lowercase all the text field input when you type any thing in your targeted text Field

```
func textField(_ textFieldToChange: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
         //just change this charectar username  it's a text field
        if textFieldToChange == username {
            let characterSetNotAllowed = CharacterSet.whitespaces
            if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from:NSCharacterSet.uppercaseLetters) {
                return false
            }
            if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSetNotAllowed, options: .caseInsensitive) {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```