# UITextField and UISearch Bar disable capital letters button - Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uisearchbar

Im working on a social network and i want usernames to only be in lower case, in the username text field how do i make the keyboard not allow capital letters (i could force the textfield.text letters into lower case after the fact but i don't really want to do that) i also need it to work for UISearchBox because searching for lower case users doesn't work to well if they can activate the capital letters button, (it returns nil in the search)

Answer (score 17):

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = .None
```

Comment: Thank you but not quite, that only disables it on the first character. I need it so that it is impossible to do even half way through a word

Comment: Swift 4.0 textField.autocapitalizationType = .none

Comment: **Swift 5.1** is the same as @Doug Voss answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe setting all three properties works like describe in my this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52489530/855261

and you can also set a **UITextField method to avoid typing capital letters**.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: .uppercaseLetters) {
        // Don't allow upper case letters
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 with swiftUI

```
TextField(“Search”, text: $userName).autocapitalization(.none)
```